# Can Google Drive transfer files from Docs to Picasa?

Tags: google-drive-api, picasa, google-picker

I see you can use Google Picker to open Web Albums, but can you transfer from Drive to Picasa directly?

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, we don't have a way to transfer data directly to or from Picasa without downloading a file and re-uploading it.

To download and re-upload a file, first [download it from the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/get), then [upload it to Picasa](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#PostPhotos) using the [Picasa Web Albums Data API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide).